# Android Market - Selling paid for upgrades (not updates)

Tags: android, google-play

I've been trying to work out whether it's possible to do the following sort of thing with Google's Android Market but can't find an answer as all my searches relating to upgrade paths are clouded with results about updating individual apps.

If I have 2 applications, lets call them Application_A and Application_B which sell for $2 and $5 respectively, is there any mechanism by which I can provide an upgrade path so that anyone who owns Application_A already can buy Application_B at a discounted price of $3, but anyone who doesn't own Application_A and just buys Application_B still pays $5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking too and it's impossible. :(

Answer (score 3):

Best approach I've seen is to sell app b for $2, and use in app purchase ($3) to unlock all it's features.

You can also have a "full" build version and sell that for $5.

You should be able to share almost all of the code in a common code base just fine, and you can even offer this to existing customers (just issue an update with the in-app purchase enabled.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't provide discounts for your apps in the Android market.